# how can I add share feature to below dart code

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:share/share.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Stop addiction',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor:Colors.black,
          title: Text('stop addiction',style:TextStyle(color:Colors.red),),centerTitle: true,actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.share,color:Colors.white70,), onPressed:Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');)
          ],
        ),
        body: _blank()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I add share feature to above code
2. When user will click on the icon share options should appear on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be

```
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.share,color:Colors.white70,), onPressed:() => Share.share('check out my website https://example.com')/*semicolon removed here*/)
```

And, remove the semicolon